# In Laravel, Is there a way to delete old revoked/expired passport tokens

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm Using Laravel passport for API implementation, When user logged into the site it creates a new token, the old ones are revoked, due to this records are getting increased day by day..

Is there anyway to delete passport expired tokens ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to check that link https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/629

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Laravel style

We'll be using [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#purging-tokens) command to purge revoked and expired tokens:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('passport:purge')->dailyAt('03:00');
    }
}
```

Comment: note that this will only work with Laravel 6.x or higher, as purge command is not available in earlier versions :)

Answer (score 4):

You should use CRON jobs for that.
Just make a command that once per day (for example) is querying the DB table for tokens that are revoked, and delete that records.

`php artisan make:command DeleteRevokedTokens`

it will generate that file in `app/Console/Commands`.
Write that `Eloquent` logic in that command `handle()` method.
Give that command a name in the `$signature` variable, and a description in `$description` variable.

Then go in `app/Console/Kernel.php` and in `schedule()` method add a line like that
`$schedule->command('yourCommandNameThatYouWroteInSignatureVariableOfYourCommand')->dailyAt('00:00');`

That's it. Now just you have to turn on your `CRON jobs`. It's useless on development, but must in production. 
To test your command, just write in terminal `php artisan yourCommandNameHere`, where `yourCommandName` is the `$signature` variable from that command. So, when you write it, it will execute it. Cron job will only handle that this command is automatically launched when you setted it in `app/Console/Kernel.php`.

Comment: Do you *really* need to add another layer of complexity to this simple task? You can just write the logic in the `$schedule->call()` callback

Answer (score 4):

Little late, but anyway someone might find it useful.

Instead of setting up a CRON job, you can use the passport events for this. Passport emits events when access token is created and when the refresh token is created. All you need to do is to register this events in the `EventServiceProvider` and then call `php artisan event:generate`

```php
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated' => [
        'App\Listeners\RevokeOldTokens',
    ],
    'Laravel\Passport\Events\RefreshTokenCreated' => [
        'App\Listeners\PruneOldTokens',
    ],
];
```

Then in `App\Listeners\PruneOldTokens` you can delete every other token that the user had before:

```php
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  AccessTokenCreated  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(AccessTokenCreated $event)
{
    Token::where([
        ['user_id', $event->userId],
        ['id', '<>', $event->tokenId]
    ])->delete();
}
```

Don't forget to import `Laravel\Passport\Token` at the top.

Note: I'm also deleting expired refresh tokens on the refresh token created event. Just add this in the listener for the refresh token created event. This way, every time a new refresh token is created for some user, all expired tokens are deleted.

```php
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  RefreshTokenCreated  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(RefreshTokenCreated $event)
{
    \DB::table('oauth_refresh_tokens')
        ->whereDate('expires_at', '<', now()->addDays(1))
        ->delete();
}
```

Comment: This is the *worst* possible way to do it. Token creation has nothing to do with Token expiration/revocation... why would you use `AccessTokenCreated` and `RefreshTokenCreated` event to trigger the cleanup? Can you imagine the amount of spam you will create (especially in a busy system). Don't let me started on the fact that most clients will create new tokens AND refresh_token with each request session...

Comment: How can you say that expiration/revocation has nothing to do with `AccessTokenCreated` and `RefreshTokenCreated` events?! Obviously you don't understand what this code does. If you did, you would see that when new `access_token` is created for some user, THEN all the other tokens for THAT SAME user are deleted. And as for the `refresh_token`, it deletes all the `refresh_token`s that are expired by a day. Furthermore, this same approach is used in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#events).

Comment: The poster want to delete expired/revoked tokens. So he can adjust the logic in the listener however he finds suitable in his case. I just show him a way how can he do it without using cron jobs (how it works in my case). And if you want to have multiple devices logged in at the same time, you can adjust the logic to support just that. The crucial thing here is that you can use the native Passport events for doing this and that you don't necessarily need to use cron job. But at the end of the day, it all comes to what works in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Artisan console command:

*php artisan passport:purge*

Answer (score 2):

This will log the user out and delete the token at the same time.

```
public function logout ()
{
    $tokenRepository = app('Laravel\Passport\TokenRepository');
    $user = auth('api')->user();

    if ($user) {
        $tokenRepository->revokeAccessToken($user->token()->id);
        $user->token()->delete();

        return response()->json(['status', 'Logged Out']);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['status', 'Already Logged Out']);
    }

}
```